# Changing the class of a .net object to a subclass

Tags: .net, oop, design-patterns

I have an OO design question.

I'm using a Factory pattern to create objects of a class appropriate to the parameters I pass the Factory. However, there are some attributes that I can only get after object creation which I want to then use to further subclass or "specialize" the type of object.

I need subclass for polimorphism to use custom logic for object with additional input parameters.

I think it's some design pattern "Redetermination object class at runtime". How can i implement it? Oh may be it is bad practice?

Comment: Do you have any code examples you could post?

Comment: I write app for measuring. To detect meas type user give some input parameters. To detect final type (class) of meas user passes though 4 screens(gui). At each next step I have to call virtual Meas.Init which is different for different types. So I need Redetermination meas type at each step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change object type at runtime. If you have instance of base class, then it will stay of base class type. But you can create new objects at runtime. Use composition instead of inheritance.

I.e. instead of inheriting from your base class, create another objects hierarchy - extract to new classes (not inherited from your base class) code which changes after your base object creation. It could be some strategy. Then provide different implementations of strategy to your base object at runtime (i.e. "specialize" base class instance).

Comment: I couldn't introduce new class, which incapsulates algorithm(Strategy). I shoud have one hierarchy. But your answer is useful. thanks

Comment: @AndrewKalashnikov your hierarchy will stay. You will just provide new dependencies to created objects. E.g. `IFoo foo = factory.GetFoo()` (thats what you have now). But instead of creating new type `FooWithRedAttribute` you extract `Color` and provide it to your foo instance: `foo.Color = Red`. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change type of instantiated object, but I see 2 possible work arounds:
1. instantiate another Factory from your inital Factory, which will eventually create object of desired type.
2. utilize Ruby's "method-missing" concept with ExpandoObject. I'm not sure if it is suitable in your case or not.